# Javascript - Browser naming conventions for event attributes confusing me

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, web

I've been wondering why there is a difference in the attribute name for an event's target/sourceElement in JavaScript for different browsers.

```
event.srcElement in Internet Explorer
event.target in most other browsers.
```

Comment: Because Microsoft used to hate web developers. Just use `event.srcElement || event.target`, that should cover most cases

Comment: First - thank you for your reply that is a great solution. I was hoping there was some more tangible happening here such as the JavaScript API changing before an early IE launch, or something. I'm still curious about the reasoning behind not adding this attribute as a by reference alias, or something? something!

Comment: No, Microsoft just decided to create their own *"standards"*. I'm trying to find a good canonical source for your reading pleasure but can't find much beyond [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer#Standards_support) at the moment

Comment: I think [this](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/184449/why-does-internet-explorer-have-so-many-incompatibilities-with-other-browsers) is a good explanation as to why they decide to make their own standards.

Answer (score 3):

Internet Explorer is known to be a rebellious browser, especially in early versions, going by its own standards with the web API.

Although it is heavily criticized for this, [we should be also thankful with it](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2012/08/22/the-innovations-of-internet-explorer/), since its rebellion has helped introduce some features that went on to become a standard, such as `innerHTML` and AJAX requests.

In this particular case, the difference in convention arises because older versions of IE use a different event model than the standard model other browsers use. With it, comes a series of differently named objects. **From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Event/target):**

> **On IE6-8, the event model is different.** Event listeners are attached
>   with the non-standard element.attachEvent() method. In this model, the
>   event object has an srcElement property, instead of the target
>   property, and it has the same semantics as event.target.

Internet Explorer started following standards *more thoroughly* in more recent versions, for instance, `attachEvent` is [completely deprecated in IE11](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms536343(v=vs.85).aspx).

This same thing happens with some other stuff, hence why you've got to use fallbacks with certain features, if you want to support older versions of IE.

**As to why they don't add aliases in Internet Explorer?** Well, they eventually and sometimes introduce the standard API and keep their own standard for a while, which I believe is the case with the event model; It seems, for instance, that IE9 supports both `addEventListener` and `attachEvent`.

**As to *why* they make their own standards, I think [the top answer in here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/184449/why-does-internet-explorer-have-so-many-incompatibilities-with-other-browsers) is a good explanation.**

Comment: No problem. Whoops, I think I accidentally made this a community wiki, I'm not sure if this belongs in there...

Comment: Thank you for adding the upshot by including the positive outcomes to a very easily poopoo'd topic, often overlooked and completely - until now, unbeknownst to me. :)

Answer (score 1):

Every time you load up a web page, the browser is turning the code it gets into a usable format which your computer understands. However the different browsers do it in slightly different ways, so sometimes exceptions need to be made for certain browsers.

The browser is a translator, sometimes the translation can be different depending on who does the translation.

In this specific case I would guess Internet explorer understand srcElement, while all the others understand target.

Comment: I understand that different browsers have different rules for interpreting CSS styles. The resultant displayed effect for say a drop shadow has to be programmatically created by the browser for your viewing pleasure. However with this particular instance of using a different object attribute name than specified in JavaScript's API was confusing me. I should have made my question more specific. I can't give up-votes yet but I like @Phil's explanation of MS deciding to create their own "standards".

Comment: I will upvote him for you since he understood the question better. I think you are allowed to accept questions